# Google display - Company

Tags: google-search

I have a website (well, I own a company). I'd like to get my website set up so that when someone searches in Google, it's looks how CNN looks, for example:

[image]

How do I tell Google to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont :) it looks at your site structure and sees if it can find a way to display your site like the screenshot

Straight from the horses mouth:

Google has not generated any sitelinks for your site. Sitelinks are completely automated, and we show them only if we think they'll be useful to the user. If your site's structure doesn't allow our algorithms to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks are relevant to the user's query, we won't show them. However, we are always working to improve how we find and display sitelinks.

Comment: frustrating i know but thats the big G's decision :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Google figures out this information from your site structure, the best you can do is to make it easy for Google to discover the structure. A [sitemap](http://sitemaps.org/) for your site helps with that.

Answer (score 1):

It's called SiteLinks :)

You can try check this article about [SiteLinks](http://www.microsystools.com/products/sitemap-generator/help/google-sitelinks-webmaster-tools/) for some speculative info on you how and when sitelinks are selected/named/shown (and how to influence it through, e.g. good page titles, URLs, internal linking etc.)

(Also notice that SiteLinks normally only show if your domain is an authority for the given search phrase.)

Comment: My domain does show up as the first result. I can't seem to understand how to use SiteLinks. You have to pay for this?

Comment: Not for normal/organic search results. Google will determine itself if SiteLinks is a good fit for your website/search-query.